# where to get images for game center?

Tags: image, game-center

Often I see games like angry birds or others that have game center in them and they all have the same images for game center buttons,achievements would be a trophy and leader boards are like a podium for 1st/2nd/3rd... where do you get these? are they apple supplied or are they just what developers have agreed on to recreate for their games?

UPDATE:

[image]
<sub>(source: [angry-birds.net](http://angry-birds.net/img/Angry-Birds-Rio-01.jpg))</sub>

See the trophy and the 213 buttons?

Comment: Could you post an image showing an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Are all of those game created by different companies / developers? otherwise I guess they just made it and re-use it all of their games.